# Connectivity good between VMs, but no connectivity between host and VM

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, connection

I have a strange situation where connectivity (ie ping, access shared folders and services) is fine between virtual machines, but not between the host and the virtuals.  I've been using Hyper-V almost every day for years and have never had a problem like this.

Note the following:

1. The host machine and all virtuals are running Windows Server 2008 r1.
2. All machines can connect to the web, and the gateway router.
3. Subnet mask and gateway reported in ipconfig are identical for all machines.
4. I can access virtuals via the Hyper-V snap-in only.

Doea anyone have suggestions about what might be wrong, or what diagnostic steps I can take?

[image]

Comment: Please paste ipconfigs. How VMs are obtain ip addresses? Probably vms are behind the nat what makes them impossible to acces from top (host) network

Comment: Please post routing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end bridging the virtual and real network solved the problem.

I have no idea how they became unbridged.

Comment: Please set this as solution.